# Python lxml: How to traverse back up a tree

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I have the following python code

```python
import lxml.etree

root = lxml.etree.parse("../../xml/test.xml")

path="./pages/page/paragraph[contains(text(),'ash')]"
para = root.xpath(path)
```

once i reach the para node, i dont want to go any further. Now i want to travel back up to the root and look at all of the `<paragraph>` nodes. Is there a way to travel back up the tree.

Or look at it this way. I want the subtree between `root` and `para`. How would i do that?

For reference, here is the xml

```xml
<document>
    <pages>
        <page>
            <paragraph>XBV</paragraph>
            <paragraph>GFH</paragraph>
        </page>
        <page>
            <paragraph>ash</paragraph>
            <paragraph>lplp</paragraph>
        </page>
    </pages>
</document>
```

now in this case, i want the nodes XBV and GFH. How is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`..` would bring you one level up the tree.

But, I think [`preceding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding) is something you are looking for:

> The preceding axis indicates all the nodes that precede the context node in the document except any ancestor, attribute and namespace nodes.

```
./pages/page/paragraph[contains(text(),'ash')]//preceding::paragraph
```

Sample code:

```
import lxml.etree


data = """
<document>
    <pages>

    <page>
       <paragraph>XBV</paragraph>

       <paragraph>GFH</paragraph>
    </page>

    <page>
       <paragraph>ash</paragraph>

       <paragraph>lplp</paragraph>
    </page>

    </pages>
</document>
"""

tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(data)
print [item.text for item in tree.xpath("./pages/page/paragraph[contains(text(),'ash')]//preceding::paragraph")]
```

Prints:

```
['XBV', 'GFH']
```

Comment: by the way, is it possible to have multiple tags in preceding? for example, can i do something like preceding::paragraph,data ?

Comment: @AbtPst you can wildcard it: `preceding-sibling::*` if this is the case. Or, you can list the elements: `preceding::*[name() = 'page' or name() = 'paragraph']`..

Comment: superb! exactly what i needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Go up and get all previous `page`(only page) node and `paragraph` node inside them and extract text from them-

```
>>>expresson = "./pages/page/paragraph[contains(text(),'ash')]//preceding::page//paragraph"
>>>x=  [i.text for i in expresson]
>>>['XBV', 'GFH']
```

Comment: thanks man! the -sibling gives me the immediate predecessor. ideally i would want all the preceding nodes.

Comment: Not gonna work as is. If you really want to apply `preceding-sibling`, you need to go one level up to the `page`, then get the `preceding-sibling::page` and then look for `paragraph` elements inside.

Comment: oh ok, cause the node that we are looking at might not have any siblings discovered. for example, we stopped at node ash. now try changing the path to "./pages/page/paragraph[contains(text(),'lplp')]//preceding-sibling::paragraph" so that here we are looking to stop at node lplp. Now this code change prints out ash as expected